# Views auto submit function

Tags: 7, views

I want to know which function is called for views auto submit function. I want to do this auto submit manually through PHP or jQuery, when some action is performed.

I mean Ajax auto submit without page refresh.

Comment: Do you mean from the Views backend itself or when you're using Views pager or exposed filters on the frontend?

Comment: views backend itself.